# Can't push docker image to internal Artifactory

Tags: docker, artifactory, docker-registry, windows-server-2016

Having an Artifactory server with a local docker repository configure.
I want to push images to that repo.

I have Windows 2016 and installed Docker:

> Docker version 1.12.2-cs2-ws-beta, build 050b611

I have creating the daemon.json configuration file in order to set the daemon to work with insecure registries and and edit the json as:

> {"insecure-registries": ["art:8080"]}

I tag my image with:

> docker tag java art:8080/java

then im trying to push it to Artifactory with:

> docker push art:8080/java

when executing this command im getting:

> The push refers to a repository
>   [art:8080/java]
>
> 932b647616fa: Preparing
>
> de57d9086f9a: Skipped foreign layer
>
> f358be10862c: Skipped foreign layer
>
> error parsing HTTP 404 response body: unexpected end of JSON input: ""

What does that menas and how can I push the image to my artifactory local repo in an insecure way?

Comment: This is probably related an Artifactory issue with supporting foreign layers - [RTFACT-10305](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/browse/RTFACT-10305)

Comment: @drorb I got now a: 'manifest invalid' error when trying to push so there is no manifest.jsob file under the docker repo in Artifactory so basically I can't pull those dockers or use them.(I saw a bug in Artifactory JIRA which saying to give delete permission to the user but his already has that). Isnt there a workaround for that? Can't think that all windows-docker-artifactory users are stuck like I do without the option to deploy\pull docker to Artifactory.

Comment: did you also try some of MS's support channels for your problem?

Comment: @Falco Alexander no, why? do you think its ms issue?